# Need assistance with android:layout_centerVertical="true"

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I'm new at programming on android, so I'm having a hard time understanding how relative layouts work. I've got most of it down, but android:layout_centerVertical="true" just isnt working when I try using it in my code. I'm supposed to put 3 textviews in order from top to bottom so it says "Happy Birthday To You" but I cant get the "Birthday" textview to center left. When I use android:layout_centerInParent="true" it centers smack in the middle and I can't move it left or right. Could someone look at my code and tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Happy" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Birthday" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="To You" />
```

Comment: When you are using Relative Layout, then you can give id to each view & then arrange other view with respect to this view. use "android:layout_below" for 'Birthday' & 'To You'

Comment: can you add an image which describe how layout you want??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center" // settext gravity as per your requirement 
        android:text="Happy"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"// settext gravity as per your requirement 
        android:text="Birthday"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="center" // settext gravity as per your requirement 
        android:text="To You"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

You can try with  **`android:gravity="center"`**

> Place the object in the center of its container in both the vertical
>   and horizontal axis, not changing its size.

```
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:gravity="left|center"  // Text will Center & left align
```

**FYI**  .

You are using RelativeLayout . For your ***TEXTVIEW*** **Vertical** issue, You should use **[android:layout_below](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_below)**.

> Positions the top edge of this view below the given anchor view ID.
>   Accommodates top margin of this view and bottom margin of anchor view.

Answer (score 0):

Use `layout_centerVertical="true"` to center view in vertical orientation

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Happy"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Birthday"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="To You"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I tried using the code you provided,                                             
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Birthday" />                                                                                          But this error message kept showing up:                                               
The attribute android:layout_centerVertical` is not supported here.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `android:gravity="center"` in parent layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Happy" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Birthday" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="To You" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

What your file produces right now is:

[image: Before]

And I assume you want is this:

[image]

So just add the following line in your root layout, this aligns all its children views horizontally in its centre

> android:gravity="center_horizontal"